# Find the Most Frequent Ordered Word Pair In a Document

Tags: algorithm

This is a problem from S. Skiena's "Algorithm. Design Manual" book, the problem statement is:

> Give an algorithm for finding an ordered word pair(e.g."New York")
>       occurring with the greatest frequency in a given webpage. 
>       Which data structure would you use? Optimize both time and space.

One obvious solution is inserting each ordered pair in a hash-map and then iterating over all of them, to find the most frequent one, however, there definitely should be a better way, can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Why should there definitely be a better way?

Comment: Is 'York New' the same as 'New York'? What about 'New. York' the same as 'New, York' the same as 'New\nYork'?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth because it uses O(n^2) time and memory, if n is the number of words in the document, which is way too much. Also, as my lecturer says, you should ask yourself "Can we do better?" :)

Comment: It uses O(n) time and memory.

Comment: @dawg I believe, punctuation is not that important here, so I suggest trying to solve it assuming, there is no punctuation at all, just a sequence of words. Moreover, "York New" and "New York" should be considered different pairs, since it is mentioned in the problem statement - we are dealing with ordered word pairs.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ah, sorry, you're right. Anyway, the question is still relevant: can it be better?

Comment: @Susan: Think of it this way; you have to visit every single word, right?  Therefore is it logically possible to do better than O(n)?

Comment: Perhaps "optimize" doesn't mean complexity but actual time and space? An array of {string, int} will use 2-3 times less space than a hash-table (at the cost of slower run-time both in complexity and wall time).

Answer (score 2):

In a text with `n` words, we have exactly `n - 1` ordered word pairs (not distinct of course). One solution is to use a max priority queue; we simply insert each pair in the max PQ with frequency 1 if not already present. If present, we increment the key. However, if we use a Trie, we don't need to represent all `n - 1` pairs separately. Take for example the following text:

> A new puppy in New York is happy with it's New York life.

The resulting Trie would look like the following:

[image]

If we store the number of occurrences of a pair in the leaf nodes, we could easily compute the maximum occurrence in linear time. Since we need to look at each word, that's the best we can do, time wise.

Working Scala code below. The official site has a [solution in Python](http://www.algorist.com/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_3.29).

```
class TrieNode(val parent: Option[TrieNode] = None,
               val children: MutableMap[Char, TrieNode] = MutableMap.empty,
               var n: Int = 0) {
  def add(c: Char): TrieNode = {
    val child = children.getOrElseUpdate(c, new TrieNode(parent = Some(this)))
    child.n += 1
    child
  }

  def letter(node: TrieNode): Char = {
    node.parent
      .flatMap(_.children.find(_._2 eq node))
      .map(_._1)
      .getOrElse('\u0000')
  }

  override def toString: String = {
    Iterator
      .iterate((ListBuffer.empty[Char], Option(this))) {
        case (buffer, node) =>
          node
            .filter(_.parent.isDefined)
            .map(letter)
            .foreach(buffer.prepend(_))

          (buffer, node.flatMap(_.parent))
      }
      .dropWhile(_._2.isDefined)
      .take(1)
      .map(_._1.mkString)
      .next()
  }
}

def mostCommonPair(text: String): (String, Int) = {
  val root = new TrieNode()

  @tailrec
  def loop(s: String,
           mostCommon: TrieNode,
           count: Int,
           parent: TrieNode): (String, Int) = {
    s.split("\\s+", 2) match {
      case Array(head, tail @ _*) if head.nonEmpty =>
        val word = head.foldLeft(parent)((tn, c) => tn.add(c))
        val (common, n, p) =
          if (parent eq root) (mostCommon, count, word.add(' '))
          else if (word.n > count) (word, word.n, root)
          else (mostCommon, count, root)

        loop(tail.headOption.getOrElse(""), common, n, p)
      case _ => (mostCommon.toString, count)
    }
  }

  loop(text, new TrieNode(), -1, root)
}
```

Inspired by the question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/103786/95996).

Answer (score 1):

I think the first point to note is that finding the most frequent ordered word pair is no more (or less) difficult than finding the most frequent word. The only difference is that instead of words made up of the letters a..z+A.Z separated by punctuation or spaces, you are looking for word-pairs made up of the letters a..z+A..Z+exactly_one_space, similarly separated by punctuation or spaces.

If your web-page has n words then there are only n-1 word-pairs. So hashing each word-pair then iterating over the hash table will O(n) in both time and memory. This should be pretty quick to do even if n is ~10^6 (i.e. the length of an average novel). I can't imagine anything more efficient unless n is fairly small, in which case the memory savings resulting from constructing an ordered list of word pairs (instead of a hash table) might outweigh the cost of increasing time complexity to O(nlogn)

Comment: Also, instead of using strings as your hash keys, you can use the positions in the text at which they occur.

Answer (score 0):

why not keep all the ordered pairs in AVL tree with 10 elements array to track top 10 ordered pairs. In AVL we would keep all the order pairs with their occurring count and top 10 will keep in the array. this way searching  of any ordered pair would be O(log N) and traversing would be O(N).

Answer (score -1):

I think we could not do better than O(n) in terms of time as one would have to see at least each element once. So time complexity cannot be optimised further.

But we can use a **trie** to optimise the space used. In a page, there are often words which are repeated, so this might lead to significant reduction in space usage. The leaf nodes in the trie cold store the frequency of the ordered pair and using two pointers to iterate in the text where one would point at the current word and second would point at previous word.

Comment: Given by the lack of explanation, sounds like you picked up the answer from the [official site](http://www.algorist.com/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_3.29)